# Glide library code not working as expected

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm using `Glide` in my project for image loading and caching. Code is as given below:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int[] screenSize() {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        return new int[]{size.x, size.y};
    }

    @BindViews(value = {R.id.logo, R.id.first, R.id.second, R.id.last})
    protected List<ImageView> sharedElements;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        final AnimatedViewPager pager = ButterKnife.findById(this, R.id.pager);
        final ImageView background = ButterKnife.findById(this, R.id.scrolling_background);
        int[] screenSize = screenSize();

        for (ImageView element : sharedElements) {
            @ColorRes int color = element.getId() != R.id.logo ? R.color.white_transparent : R.color.color_logo_log_in;
            DrawableCompat.setTint(element.getDrawable(), ContextCompat.getColor(this, color));
        }
        //load a very big image and resize it, so it fits our needs
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(R.drawable.busy)
                .asBitmap()
                .override(screenSize[0] * 2, screenSize[1])
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
                .into(new ImageViewTarget<Bitmap>(background) {
                    @Override
                    protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                        background.setImageBitmap(resource);
                        background.post(() -> {
                            //we need to scroll to the very left edge of the image
                            //fire the scale animation
                            background.scrollTo(-background.getWidth() / 2, 0);
                            ObjectAnimator xAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(background, View.SCALE_X, 4f, background.getScaleX());
                            ObjectAnimator yAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(background, View.SCALE_Y, 4f, background.getScaleY());
                            AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
                            set.playTogether(xAnimator, yAnimator);
                            set.setDuration(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.duration));
                            set.start();
                        });
                        pager.post(() -> {
                            AuthAdapter adapter = new AuthAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), pager, background, sharedElements);
                            pager.setAdapter(adapter);
                        });
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

When I try to run my code, I get below errors:

> error: cannot find symbol variable RESULT
>   error: cannot find symbol method asBitmap()

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Put `asBitmap()` right after your `with()` call:

```
Glide.with(this).asBitmap()
```

See the documenation at https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html#picking-resource-types

Comment: Changed as you suggested, now it gives another error: `error: cannot find symbol method override(int,int)`

Comment: Can you try this: 

`Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load().apply(new RequestOptions().override(screenSize[0] * 2, screenSize[1])).diskCacheStrategy().into()`

Comment: I should use `override` because it takes a larger image and resizes it to the screen

Comment: I modified as you said, getting this error: `error: cannot find symbol variable RESULT`

Comment: Which version of Glide are you using?

Comment: I'm using `Glide 4.7.1`